# Logstash shuts down 2-3 seconds after starting on port 9600

Tags: logstash

I am on windows, i cmd to logstash dir, and run it with

```
.\bin\logstash.bat -f ..\simple-config.conf
```

My .conf file is:

```
input {
file {
    type=>"users-ws-log"
    path=>"C:/Users/nsun/Desktop/Education/Spring_Micro/workspace/PhotoAppApiUsers/users-ws.log"
}
file {
    type=>"albums-ws-log"
    path=>"C:/Users/nsun/Desktop/Education/Spring_Micro/workspace/PhotoAppApiAlbums/albums-ws.log"
}
    }
    output {

        if[type] == "users-ws-log" {

            elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "users-ws-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }

        } else if[type] == "albums-ws-log" {

            elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "albums-ws-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }

        }

        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

I have tried the path with \, /, \, but none of them fix the issue.
I saw someone else saying every line needs to end with a newline so I added carriage return to last line and it does not fix the issue.

The console output is:

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/C:/Users/nsun/Desktop/Misc_Programs/ELK/logstash-7.8.0/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.11.1.jar) to field java.io.Console.cs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Users/nsun/Desktop/Misc_Programs/ELK/logstash-7.8.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-06-19T19:27:35,594][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-06-19T19:27:35,676][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.8.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.11.1 (2.5.7) 2020-03-25 b1f55b1a40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 13.0.2+8 on 13.0.2+8 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2020-06-19T19:27:36,050][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"C:/Users/nsun/Desktop/Misc_Programs/ELK/simple-config.conf"}
[2020-06-19T19:27:36,073][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
[2020-06-19T19:27:36,492][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-06-19T19:27:41,167][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

Appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: I made sure that users-ws.log and albums-ws.log are both present in their respective dir

Comment: i ran .\bin\logstash.bat -f ..\simple-config.conf --debug
with the debug option but it doesn't show anything new between starting on port 9600 and shutting down

Comment: I tried it with a very simple .conf file
`input {
    # Accept input from the console.
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    # Add filter here. This sample has a blank filter.
}

output {
    # Output to the console.
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}` and it didn't shut down, so there has to be something wrong with my .conf but I am new to logstash and am confused on what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

found my problem, a very silly one -> simple-config.conf is in the src code dir, so it should be .\bin\logstash.bat -f simple-config.conf, now it works

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. In my case, block of output was not properly close with curly bracket.